# How do I avoid FileNotFoundException for vshost32 when using AssemblyScanner FromAssembliesInPath method?

Tags: .net, exception, ninject

An exception is getting thrown when I use the `AssemblyScanner.FromAssembliesInPath` method.

How do I fix this problem?

I am using [the Ninject.Extensions.Conventions extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions).  I am using versions I just grabbed from NuGet an hour ago.

- Ninject 2.2.1.4 Updated 5/7/2011
- Ninject.Extensions.Conventions 2.2.0.5 Updated 5/7/2011

I am using the assembly scanner like this:

```
Kernel.Scan(x =>
{
    x.FromAssembliesMatching("*.dll");
    x.FromAssembliesInPath(".");
    x.WhereTypeInheritsFrom(typeof(DbContext));
    x.BindWithDefaultConventions();
    x.InTransientScope();
});
```

When trying to run my program from Visual Studio, this exception gets thrown:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'vshost32, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This gets thrown by this line of code:

```
x.FromAssembliesInPath(".");
```

Here's the whole stack trace:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'vshost32, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)

   at System.AppDomain.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.AssemblyScanner.<FindAssemblies>d__10.MoveNext() in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.extensions.conventions\src\Ninject.Extensions.Conventions\AssemblyScanner.cs:line 238
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.AssemblyScanner.From(IEnumerable`1 assemblies, Predicate`1 filter) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.extensions.conventions\src\Ninject.Extensions.Conventions\AssemblyScanner.cs:line 300
   at Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.AssemblyScanner.FromAssembliesInPath(String path, Predicate`1 assemblyFilter) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.extensions.conventions\src\Ninject.Extensions.Conventions\AssemblyScanner.cs:line 325
   at Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.AssemblyScanner.FromAssembliesInPath(String path) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.extensions.conventions\src\Ninject.Extensions.Conventions\AssemblyScanner.cs:line 312
   at (Line for my code, `x.FromAssembliesInPath(".");`)
   at Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.ExtensionsForIKernel.Scan(IKernel kernel, Action`1 scan) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.extensions.conventions\src\Ninject.Extensions.Conventions\ExtensionsForIKernel.cs:line 43
   at (Line for my code, `Kernel.Scan(x =>`)
   at Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule.OnLoad(IKernel kernel) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Modules\NinjectModule.cs:line 60
   at Ninject.KernelBase.Load(IEnumerable`1 modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 222
   at Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(IComponentContainer components, INinjectSettings settings, INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 102
   at Ninject.KernelBase..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 57
   at Ninject.StandardKernel..ctor(INinjectModule[] modules) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\StandardKernel.cs:line 31
   at (Line for my code, `using(IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new SomeModule()))`)
```

Comment: The way to avoid this notorious exception is to return an enum value instead:  http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Comment: I agree.  If you don't have a sense of humour then please ignore any links to thedailywtf.

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer: Oh, lol!  I totally blanked out on that.  Thanks for the link, will delete the comment :)

Comment: It is trying to load the Visual Studio hosting process.  Yes, that's not going to work.  Can't you be a bit more selective?  *.dll should be plenty already.

Comment: @HansPassant: I thought I was being more selective by specifying "only the current directory".  I guess I just don't understand how this library works, as the "preview" example I read says that each of those lines filters more.  Do you know about any docs for this thing?

Comment: @HansPassant: They also do the same thing in their example - http://innovatian.com/2010/02/ninject-extensions-conventions-preview/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug but won't be fixed anymore because the current beta is a complete reimplementation with a new interface.

Replacing `FromAssembliesInPath` by `From(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())` should do the same. (or remove it completely if you are not creating an executable) All the dll's are loaded already by `FromAssembliesMatching("*.dll")` and the only acceptable exe assembly is the running assembly.

Comment: +1; Sounds great :)  I'll try it out when I get in to work.  I'm pretty sure this will solve the problem tho.  Question: Do each of these lines *filter* the existing selected assemblies, or do they potentially pull in additional assemblies?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. But yes if the assemblies reference other ones (e.g. System.SomeSystemAssembly) they will be loaded by .NET of course. But those assemblies won't be scanned.

Comment: I guess it might be pointless to comment if the interface is changing.  But I kind of expected these lines to do nothing *themselves* and to work like the SQL or Linq `where` clause - `x.FromAssembliesMatching("*.dll");` to add a filter that accepts only DLLs, `x.FromAssembliesInPath(".");` to add a filter that accepts only assemblies in the current path.  Do each of these actually *add* assemblies rather than filter?

Comment: See this Linq, as it is where I got this idea - http://innovatian.com/2010/02/ninject-extensions-conventions-preview/?

Comment: ...and now that I reread it, I'm betting those functions are additive, not filtering.

Comment: Now I understand. Yes they are additive.

Comment: One more question... is there something built in for binding types to their base types?  I'm already filtering on base type, so this type of automated binding makes sense to me.  I've already created a very simple generic `IBindingGenerator` to solve this, but I wondered if there was something built in that I'm missing.  Regex and Default seem to only want to bind to interfaces.  Will there be something to support this when the new one comes out, or at least will it be just as easy to implement it myself?

Comment: The new one has built in support. For the current one you must implement your own IBindingGenerator

Comment: I decided to make it a full-fledged question so I can share the solution and so you can mention the new library supporting it directly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499955