# How do I use the Ninject Conventions library to bind to a base type that isn't an interface?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm trying to scan for a set of components that implement a specific base class in the assemblies in the same directory as my application.  I need to do this as a sort of plugin-style architecture, as my application uses these types to populate other components.

[Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) supports scanning assemblies in the local directory, so I decided to give it a shot.

The problem is that the binding generators that library provides (`DefaultBindingGenerator` and `RegexBindingGenerator`) will only bind components to interfaces that they implement.  They won't bind to non-interface base types.

How do I use this library to bind by convention to a base class, rather than an interface?

I am using [the version currently on NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ninject.extensions.conventions) - 2.2.0.5

My current convention-based binding code looks like this:

```
Kernel.Scan(x =>
{
    x.FromAssembliesMatching("*.dll");
    x.WhereTypeInheritsFrom<BaseType>();

    // I've tried both DefaultBindingGenerator and RegexBindingGenerator
    x.BindWith<DefaultBindingGenerator>();

    x.InTransientScope();
});
```

When I try to resolve the components, nothing is returned:

```
var myTypes = Kernel.GetAll<BaseType>();
int count = myTypes.Count(); // Always returns zero
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [the current code base up on GitHub](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions), you can use [the `BaseBindingGenerator`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/BindingGenerators/BaseBindingGenerator.cs).

In the codebase I have (the one currently on NuGet - 2.2.0.5), I solved this using a custom `IBindingGenerator`.  It was fairly simple to write once I looked at [the sources for the existing binding generators](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/blob/9942fe3b8588b4998aae3f104922f7e77a18c533/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/DefaultBindingGenerator.cs).

```
public class BaseTypeBindingGenerator<TBase> : IBindingGenerator
{
    private static readonly Type baseType = typeof(TBase);

    public void Process( Type type, Func<IContext, object> scopeCallback,
        IKernel kernel )
    {
        if ( type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract || type.BaseType != baseType)
        {
            return;
        }

        kernel.Bind(baseType).To(type).InScope(scopeCallback);
    }
}
```

I used it like this:

```
Kernel.Scan(x =>
{
    x.FromAssembliesMatching("*.dll");
    x.WhereTypeInheritsFrom<BaseType>();

    x.BindWith<BaseTypeBindingGenerator<BaseType>>();

    x.InTransientScope();
});

// ...

var myTypes = Kernel.GetAll<BaseType>();
int count = myTypes.Count(); // Didn't return zero!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update on Merlyn´s answer, I am using ninject extensions conventions 3.2, and the signature has changed a little bit...

```
public class BaseTypeBindingGenerator<TBase> : IBindingGenerator
{
    private static readonly Type baseType = typeof (TBase);

    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        if (type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract || type.BaseType != baseType)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>>();
        }

        return new [] { bindingRoot.Bind(baseType).To(type) };
    }
}
```